# Adding a note to transaction

Tags: paypal

I am trying to add a Note to the transaction, so when I receive the payment email I see something in the Notes/Message section. Does anyone know what object it should get attached to?

Answer (score 0):

Both the API and HTML systems support the `CUSTOM` field. This value is accepted and passed back to you in the same fashion you sent. So if you need a message that is the field to use.